# Return array, ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am a really newbie using ctypes. I am loading a windows dll file, and trying to read the array `GetDfuFileInfo` returns. I actually ended up on loading the file in ctypes because I dont know how to pass a `dfu_file*` pointer to the `GetDfuFileInfo` function. Is this even possible?

C++ functions example usage:

```
dfu_file* TheFile = ReadDfuFile(const char*);
dfu_file_info* Info = GetDfuFileInfo(dfu_file*);
```

Python code:

```
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('dfulib.dll')
func = lib.ReadDfuFile
func.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
func("file.dvu")
```

---

**edit**

Also tried this:

```
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('dfulib.dll')
func = lib.ReadDfuFile
func.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

FileInfo = lib.GetDfuFileInfo
FileInfo.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
FileInfo.restype = None

s = func(r'file.dvu')
s = ctypes.cast(s, ctypes.c_char_p)

print FileInfo(s.value)
```

Produces the exception:

`WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000016`

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are `dfu_file` and `dfu_file_info`? Are these C++ classes, or typedef's for C structs?

Comment: BTW, you can use `lib.ReadDfuFile` and `func("file.dvu")` or `func(b"file.dvu")` (Python 3).

Comment: @eryksun C++ classes. Thanks for the tips - edited the code `:)`.

Comment: Since the function names aren't mangled, the C++ library is wrapped with an `extern "C"` API. In this case, typically C++ objects are treated as opaque pointers, for which `c_void_p` works. Getting data from an object relies on a function that takes a reference to the object and returns a C type, i.e. scalar or struct/array. If that's not available already, then consider learning SWIG, Boost.Python, or Cython to wrap the C++ interface directly.

Answer (score -1):

Sample code looks, This code invokes [GetFileAttributesA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from kernel32.dll

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
<WinDLL 'kernel32.dll', handle 77260000 at 2241ad0>
>>> windll.kernel32
<WinDLL 'kernel32', handle 77260000 at 225c2f0>
>>> windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesA("c:/test/1.txt")
32
```

You can refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html for details

Comment: This is what my code is doing actually. Now I need to argument a pointer to the `GetDfuFileInfo` from `ReadDfuFile` output.